# What regression model to use?

Tags: regression, experiment-design

I am trying to conduct a study on how public transport use changes with the introduction of a road pricing policy, what regression model should I be using?

1) A simple Log-linear model
2) A Difference log-linear model
3) A Log-linear panel data model.

Comment: Use what to measure "public transport use changes"?

Comment: Can you please provide more information for us?  How are you  measuring 'public transport use?' Is it count data like ticket sales, samples of people through ticket gates etc.?  What are your other variables in the model?  Is the 'road pricing policy' a binary outcome: before/after?  We can't really help without a little more info.

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to statistical analysis so bare with me. So basically, public transport use will be measured by the use of data already provided (which is basically passenger numbers). Indeed ,road pricing policy will be a binary outcome of before/ after. I was also contemplating what I should use for the control variables in this case, perhaps improvements to infrastructure is one or tourism.